# Eclipse RCP plugin View

Tags: eclipse-rcp

I have an view with an image(gif) of fixed size but when i re-size window or view its not adapting according to respective window or view. Can any one suggest some solution please?

Comment: I guess it is layout problem, some code would be useful

Comment: public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {
  composite Component = new Composite (parent, SWT.EMBEDDED | SWT.BORDER | SWT.NO_BACKGROUND);
  component.setLayout(new FillLayout());
  component.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.CENTER, SWT.CENTER, true, true, 1, 1));
  ImageDescriptor imageDesc = Activator.getImageDescriptor("icons/introductionimage.gif");

  Image image = imageDesc.createImage();
  Label label = new Label(component, SWT.SHADOW_IN);
         label.setImage(image);
}

Comment: image is of fixed size, so do you think it will adapt to view by changing layout?

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a layout issue - your Label/Image is not being told to 'fill' the available space, and instead to render at it's natural size.  See [this article](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-Understanding-Layouts/index.html) for more information on layouts, particularly the area the shows an example of this code:

```
gridData.horizontalAlignment = GridData.FILL;
gridData.grabExcessHorizontalSpace = true;
```